# django filter not working properly with custom added field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have created a django admin view with **list_display** and custom created filter using **list_filter** in a Django project. (using **Django 1.11**)

Problem: filter is displaying fine for the 'All' selection but not for the values ('Yes', 'No').
It gives the following error when click the filter value.

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'IsWithinRange' into field. Choices are: date_created, id, predicted_result, user_question

Code as follows:

```
class IsWithinRangeFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Is Within Range'
    parameter_name = 'IsWithinRange'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('Yes', 'Yes'),
            ('No', 'No'),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        value = self.value()
        logger.info('value :{}\n' .format(value))
        if value == 'Yes':
            return queryset.filter(IsWithinRange='Yes')
        elif value == 'No':
            return queryset.filter(IsWithinRange='No')
        return queryset

class CoreLogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):       

    readonly_fields = ['date_created']
    list_display = ('user_question', '_predicted_result', 'date_created', 'IsWithinRange')
    list_filter = (IsWithinRangeFilter,)    #without this system works fine

    def IsWithinRange(self, row):
    """showing user questions only within score range (0.5~0.8)"""

        ...
        score = <some value extract from row and then cast it to float value>
        fscore = float(score)

        if fscore >= 0.5 and fscore < 0.8:            
            return 'Yes'
        else:
            return 'No'
```

※without the filter it works fine.
There are many questions relating to this kind of problems but neither of one worked for me

Comment: Does `def IsWithinRange` need to be defined in the `models.Model` class rather than the `admin.ModelAdmin` class?

Comment: HenryM: It didn't work. Thanks for your help